# Added as Admin apple developer program (company/Organisation), but Certificates, Ids and Profiles options not there in apple developer portal

Tags: ios, certificate, admin

I have been added as an Admin in an apple developer program (company/Organisation). But when I login to my apple developer account i am not able to see the team in which i have been added as admin, and not able to see Certificates

[image]Ids and profiles section.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions only. It's not a generic support site f. ex. for how accounts in certain sites work. You need to contact f. ex. apple support for that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming